# Handling exceptions in axon when listening to the same event multiple times in same spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cqrs, axon

We are in the process of integrating axon to our existing spring boot application. We are using Axon 4.1.2 and Axon Server currently.

For example in the registration process, we fire a `RegisterCommand`, which is read by the `RegisterAggregate` and which fires the `RegistrationDoneEvent`.

There are two `EventHandlers` listening to this `RegistrationDoneEvent`. Which are `RegistrationNeo4jEventHandler` and `RegistrationSqlEventHandler`.

Everything works fine when there are no exceptions. However, when there IS an exception, let's say the `Neo4JEventHandler` receives the event if there is an exception, then the `SqlEventHandler` sill gets called and it seems everything is still rolled back on the `SqlEventHandler` even though the `SqlEventHandler` ran successfully.

How can we make it so that the `SqlEventHandler` complete and commits BUT the `Neo4JEventHandler` retries?

Secondly, how do we stop the retrying of the event entirely upon failure? Lets say if we had four event handlers (HandlerA, HandlerB, HandlerC, HandlerD) listening to the **SAME** event. If HandlerC fails we want to trigger it to be retried when we lets say fixed the underlying issue BUT also make sure that the other handlers which listened to the **SAME** event are not rerun.

The following code snippets include the aggregate and the event handlers.

**RegisterAggregate**

```
@Aggregate
public class RegisterAggregate {

    ....

    @CommandHandler
    public RegisterAggregate(RegisterCommand command) {
        apply(new RegistrationDoneEvent(command));
    }
}
```

**RegistrationSqlEventHandler**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class RegistrationSqlEventHandler { 

    @EventHandler
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public void on(RegistrationDoneEvent event) {
        ....
    }
}
```

**RegistrationNeo4jEventHandler**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class RegistrationNeo4jEventHandler { 

    @EventHandler
    public void on(RegistrationDoneEvent event) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will break down my answer into two, as you have posed not one, but two questions.
Firstly, let's talk about this question of yours:

> How can we make it so that the `RegistrationSqlEventHandler` complete and commits BUT the `RegistrationNeo4jEventHandler` retries?

From the naming it is already very evident both Event Handling Components (i.e. the class *you* write containing `@EventHandler` annotated methods) serve an entirely different Query Model. The first is going towards are RDBMS, whilst the second serves the purpose of updating a Graph Model through Neo4j.

As such I find it highly likely that you would eventually have differing non-functional requirements for both. To be able to allow differing configuration for these, you will have to use distinct [Event Processor](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/event-processing/event-processors) instances for both. The Event Processor, the component in charge of managing the technical aspect of providing the events to *your* event handlers, as the place to configure things like exception handling, threading numbers, batch sizes, etc.

Note that Event Processors come in two flavors: the `SubscribingEventProcessor` and the `TrackingEventProcessor`. These can shortly be described as an event push and an event pull mechanism, with the latter being the default as it enforces further segregation.

To configure distinct event processors for both, you can either use the Configuration API provided by Axon. For Event Processor, that means interacting with the `EventProcessingConfigurer`. With it you can define different event processors, and later on assign your event handling components to the right instance. A short hand which you can employ is to add the `@ProcessingGroup` annotation on both event handling components, with distinct names in it. 
Especially if you are in a Spring Boot environment, this will suffice as far as configuring goes.

Doing this segregation will ensure that exception scenarios within the `RegistrationNeo4jEventHandler` cannot have any undesired impact on the `RegistrationSqlEventHandler` and vice versa.

---

Secondly, let's move to your other question:

> Secondly, how do we stop the retrying of the event entirely upon failure?

To this end you will have to adjust the exception handling of your event handling process. Axon derives two levels of exception handling when it comes to event handling components:

1. The `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler` -> In charge of handling exception thrown by the `@EventHandler` annotated methods.
2. The `ErrorHandler` -> In charge of handling exception thrown *within* the Event Processor.

The default implementations of these will respectively log the errors (with the `LoggingErrorHandler`) and propagate the exception (with the `PropagatingErrorHandler`).

FYI, the reference guide has [this](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/event-processing/event-processors#error-handling) to say on error handling for Event Processors.

In this question, you are further specifying your case with distinct event handling functions. Again, if you don't want to influence failures from one event handling to cause problems for another, you will likely want to segregate these concerns with distinct event processors.

Mind you though, if these four event handlers your are exemplifying are just updating a query model, then a subsequent call should just perform the same operation without any side effects. If these event handlers however perform some other (external) activity, like sending an email, that definitely warrants segregation of the given Event Handling Component into a distinct Event Processor which you wouldn't want to retry/replay.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up a lot of things, `@ProcessingGroup` is key it seems. An additional question, I haven't gotten around to testing yet, but let's say in a production environment, if EventC fails (subscribing to `GenericCommonEvent`) and I want to replay just EventC without EventA or EventB (even though they listened to the same event) how would that be possible? I am assuming segregation by `@ProcessingGroup` would allow to only trigger a certain processing group for the particular event?

Comment: Also from what I gather `ErrorHandler` is more specific to exceptions thrown from within the axon framework itself? While the other is from the EventHandler (event logic) itself correct?

Comment: (1) If with EventA, EventB and EventC, you mean an Event Handling Component as I described it, than yes, your assumption is correct. Segregating those classes in distinct Event Processors allows for more fine grained replay logic.
(2) Correct, the `ErrorHandler` level is for framework exceptions whilst the `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler` is for the exceptions thrown by the users code.